# How to Replicate result that probabilities in included table are different 7 times?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value, nonparametric, replicability

Question: In the table at the bottom of this question, the total number of times that $\hat{P}(x;z) > \hat{P}_y(x;z) $ and $\hat{P}(y;z)>\hat{P}_x(y;z)$ is 7.

- **Can someone please replicate this result and explain to me what procedure? they used and why**

---

Note: The table is from [Tversky (1972)](https://psycnet.apa.org/journals/rev/79/4/281/), and

- $\hat{P}_y(x;z)$ and $\hat{P}_x(y;z)$ comes from asking the subject to choose an object  from the triple $\{x,y,z\}$ 30 times
- $\hat{P}(x;z)$ comes from asking the subject to choose an object  from the pair $\{x,z\}$ 20 times
- $\hat{P}(y;z)$ comes from asking the subject to choose an object  from the pair $\{y,z\}$ 20 times

I tried doing Chi-Squared tests for the proportions, but I did not come up with the correct results.

---

Also, the exact statement from the paper that I am asking how to replicate is: (emphasis mine)

> Out of 16 individual comparisons in each task (two per subject), equation 16 was satisfied in 13 and 15 cases, respectively, in Tasks B and C (p < .05 in each case5), and **only in 7 cases in Task A.** Essentially the same result was found in additional analyses.

Where equation 16 is [image]

[image]

---

Here is the table for task B incase it is useful.

- Note in the quote he says their was success in 13 cases in tasks B, **and gives a P-value**

[image: Table with task B]

Answer (score 0):

> ...the total number of times that $\hat{P}(x;z) > \hat{P}_y(x;z) $ and $\hat{P}(y;z)>\hat{P}_x(y;z)$ is 7.
>
> - **Can someone please replicate this result..**

It is a little counting error. It should be 8 instead of 7.

[image: table with highlights for cases]

Or possibly the table contains an error and the seven had been (correctly) counted on a different table.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought maybe he just counted occurrences, but for tasks B and C it is stated "(p<.05 in each case)" so I assumed there was a statistical test done. And That the statistical test eliminated one of the eight cases. Perhaps not, I cannot be sure. I have added a table for task 2 to the question though incase it sheds some light.

Comment: @user106860 those p-values may have been computed based on the number of occurrences and the hypothesis that the probability is 50% (which is tricky because besides bigger and smaller they can also be equal and the hypothetical probability should not be exactly equal to 50%). Or they are calculated based on camparing the observations as counts in a contingency table, and using a chi-squared test.

Comment: About that second case, the chi-squared test is a test for whether the distributions are different and not whether theeans are different. One can instead also use a generalised linear model (with a binomial family as the distribution).